# Append model to array in Swift only printing last item added

Tags: swift

Im not sure what I am missing here, but it "looks" right to me.

I have the following two variables at the top of my view controller:

```
var itemSpecifics: ItemSpecifics!
var itemSpecificsArray = [ItemSpecifics]()
```

I make a call into a API and do the following when its successful:

```
self.itemSpecifics = ItemSpecifics()
self.itemSpecificsArray.removeAll()
```

Here is the area where I am getting information and adding it into itemSpecifics.

```
if let getItemSpecifics = item["ItemSpecifics"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let getNameValueList = getItemSpecifics["NameValueList"] as? NSArray {
        print("game value list count \(getNameValueList.count)")
        for i in 0..<getNameValueList.count {
            if let getName = getNameValueList[i] as? NSDictionary {
                if let itemName = getName["Name"] as? String {
                    print(itemName)
                    self.itemSpecifics._itemSpecificName = itemName
                }
                if let getValue = getName["Value"] as? NSArray {
                    let itemValue = getValue[0] as? String
                    self.itemSpecifics._itemSpecificValue = itemValue!
                    print("-- \(itemValue!)")
                }
            }
            //End The Condition Information
            self.itemSpecificsArray.append(self.itemSpecifics)
        }
    }
}
```

So, its being printed correctly.

```
Professionally Graded
-- Not Graded
Sport
-- Baseball-MLB
Product
-- Lot
Player
-- Derek Jeter
Team
-- New York Yankees
Card Manufacturer
-- Topps
League
-- Major Leagues
Era
-- Modern (1981-Now)
Original/Reprint
-- Original
```

However, when I do this:

```
for i in 0..<self.itemSpecificsArray.count {
    print(self.itemSpecificsArray[i].itemSpecificName)
    print("** \(self.itemSpecificsArray[i].itemSpecificValue)")
}
```

It prints the following:

```
Original/Reprint
** Original
Original/Reprint
** Original
Original/Reprint
** Original
Original/Reprint
** Original
Original/Reprint
** Original
Original/Reprint
** Original
Original/Reprint
** Original
Original/Reprint
** Original
Original/Reprint
** Original
```

Here is my class for ItemSpecifics.

```
class ItemSpecifics {
    var _itemSpecificName: String!
    var _itemSpecificValue: String!

    var itemSpecificName : String {
        if _itemSpecificName == nil {
            _itemSpecificName = ""
        }
        return _itemSpecificName
    }

    var itemSpecificValue : String {
        if _itemSpecificValue == nil {
            _itemSpecificValue = ""
        }
        return _itemSpecificValue
    }

}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: You only have one instance of `ItemSpecifics`. You keep updating its properties and adding that instance to the array, so you have a single object in the array multiple times

Comment: ahhhh....  i need to set a new ItemSpecifics() right after the for code to create a new one. duh. dumb mistake. thanks.

Comment: Why is your class setup with separate properties and computed properties?

Comment: @rmaddy im still new with swift, this was a class setup i saw. im easy to mold if you have a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a single instance of `ItemSpecifics` - you keep updating the properties of that one instance and adding it to the array, so in the end your array holds multiple references to the one instance and that one instance has the last values you assigned.

You can make your code much more "Swifty" - Use a `struct` rather than a class, which gives immutability; You shouldn't generally use that form of "_" private properties; you can just make a property read-only, but with a struct you won't need to any way.

Also, don't use `NS...` foundation classes in Swift unless it is unavoidable.

```
struct ItemSpecifics {
    let name: String
    let value: String
}


if let getItemSpecifics = item["ItemSpecifics"] as? [String:Any],
   let getNameValueList = getItemSpecifics["NameValueList"] as? [[String:Any]] {

   for nameValueList in getNameValueList {
        if let name = nameValueList["Name"] as? String,
           let value = nameValueList["Value"] as? String {
                let newItem = ItemSpecifics(name: name, value: value)
                self.itemSpecificsArray.append(newItem)
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks. ill have to come back to this when its time to refractor the code.